# DateTime comparing by internal ticks?

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, .net-4.0

I looked at DateTime Equals implementation :

```
public bool Equals(DateTime value)
{
    return (this.InternalTicks == value.InternalTicks);
}
```

and then look at internalticks

```
internal long InternalTicks
{
    [TargetedPatchingOptOut("Performance critical to inline across NGen image boundaries")]
    get
    {
        return (((long) this.dateData) & 0x3fffffffffffffffL);
    }
}
```

And then I noticed this number : `0x3fffffffffffffffL`

which is : `4611686018427387903`

But *more* interesting is its *binary* representation :

```
00111111 11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111
^^
||
```

*Please notice the arrows*

I could have understand if *only the left* arrow would have been `0` ( positive representation)

- But why the second one is also `0` ?
- Also , why would i every want it to be `&` with a `1111....` number ?  if I want to display `5` I don't have to do `5 & 1` , just 5.

Any help?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can get this kind of information from the [Reference Source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/netframework.aspx).  The most relevant declarations in dd/ndp/clr/src/bcl/system/datetime.cs:

```
    private const UInt64 TicksMask             = 0x3FFFFFFFFFFFFFFF;
    private const UInt64 FlagsMask             = 0xC000000000000000;
    private const UInt64 LocalMask             = 0x8000000000000000;
    private const Int64 TicksCeiling           = 0x4000000000000000;
    private const UInt64 KindUnspecified       = 0x0000000000000000;
    private const UInt64 KindUtc               = 0x4000000000000000;
    private const UInt64 KindLocal             = 0x8000000000000000;
    private const UInt64 KindLocalAmbiguousDst = 0xC000000000000000;
    private const Int32 KindShift = 62;
```

Note how the *Kind* values map to those two bits.

```
    public DateTime(long ticks, DateTimeKind kind) {
        // Error checking omitted
        //...
        this.dateData = ((UInt64)ticks | ((UInt64)kind << KindShift));
    }
```

Comment: So putting zeros at the left(2 zeros) is like comparing without the DateTimeKind...right?

Comment: Right.  It is a *mask*, using the & operator masks out the values of those bits and makes them zero.

Comment: @RoyiNamir Yes, it ignores the `Kind` when comparing by masking it out. (Bad decision IMO)

Comment: @CodesInChaos so you use in your c# only DateTimeOffset  when you compare times ?

Answer (score 5):

The `dateData` field is used like a [bit field](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_field) to store multiple values in a compact format.

The top two bits store the [DateTimeKind](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/shx7s921.aspx), which has one of four possible values: Unspecified, Local (internally there are two variants), or Utc. These four values can be stored in two bits.

The bottom 62 bits store the ticks. The operation `x & 0x3fffffffffffffffL` is a bitwise-and operation, also sometimes called [masking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mask_%28computing%29). It returns only the bits that correspond to the ticks.

Comment: Internally it actually has 4 different values. There are two different variants of `Local` which interact differently with DST switching.

Comment: @RoyiNamir I don't understand what your edit wants to say, but Mark's answer is correct.

Comment: @CodesInChaos Hans already showed it in his answer. for example - I didn't know the UTC has value of x  while LOCAL has value of Y - I thought it is supposed to be in the enum. but it is written in another place.

Comment: @MarkByers there's a lot of enums with value in .net.(well not all of them... I just searched a bit with reflector and some have values and some aren't). if a future version adds an element they can append a value and not replace....no ?

Comment: oops ... forgot that they all start with 0. sorry.